What is the address of the noop program?
Other spl programs have a fixed address (usually where the first few characters represent the purpose of the program), for example the Token Program's address is always TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA, the Stake Program is Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111 etc. . What is the address of the noop program?

While it's certainly possible to write and deploy your own no-op program, there is one that was created to work with account compression, source at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/account-compression/programs/noop and deployed to https://explorer.solana.com/address/noopb9bkMVfRPU8AsbpTUg8AQkHtKwMYZiFUjNRtMmV
